# Android Studio, Volley, api response is not shown at the first time click

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

This is simple project, I am getting json data(as a string) from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 using Volley

1. I have seperated the Activity, Logic(Using Presenter) and Service (which will talk with the rest service ,using POST, GET method etc..)
2. Now, in the activity, there is a login button and its click listener (which its implementation is in WelcomePresenter)
3. When user enters a email and password, (don't confuse yourself with email it is just future feature) I am merging the string "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + userpassword in the service class and doing GET method.
4. If response http status code is 200, i am opening new activity which will print the just response, otherwise staying same activity and make toast message "fill the areas"
5. Here it what happens;

   - When I click Login button(I have enters password as 100, therefore I am doing GET method https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/100)
   - However at the first click Toast message occurs, after many clicks the new activity opens)

Here is the WelcomeView

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WelcomeView {
    private WelcomePresenter welcomeBasePresenter;
    private EditText usermail, userpassword;
    private Button loginButton;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Service restService;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

         this.usermail = findViewById(R.id.welcome_activity_edittext_username);
         this.userpassword = findViewById(R.id.welcome_activity_edittext_userpassword);
         this.loginButton = findViewById(R.id.welcome_activity_button_login);
         this.requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
         this.restService = new ServiceImpl(this.requestQueue);

         this.welcomeBasePresenter = new WelcomePresenterImpl(this, this.restService);

         this.loginButton.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
         String usermail = this.usermail.getText().toString();
         String password = this.userpassword.getText().toString();
         this.welcomeBasePresenter.loginButtonListener(usermail, password);
         });
    }
    public void loadErrorMessage(String... errorMessage) {
      //make toast message
    }
    public void loadUserPageActivity() {
       // load new activity
    }
}
```

Here is the WelcomePresenter

```
public class WelcomePresenterImpl implements WelcomePresenter {
    private WelcomeView welcomeView;
    private Service service;

    public WelcomePresenterImpl(WelcomeView responsibleView, Service restServis){
        this.welcomeView = responsibleView;

        this.service = restServis;
    }

    public void loginButtonListener(String usermail, String userpassword) {
        service.validateUser(usermail, userpassword);
        if (service.getUserRegisterHttpCode() == 200){
        this.welcomeView.loadUserPageActivity(service.getJsonData());
        }else{
            this.welcomeView.loadErrorMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Service class which talks with backend

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
    private String jsonData;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private int userRegisterHttpCode;

    public ServiceImpl(RequestQueue requestQueue){
        this.requestQueue = requestQueue;
    }

    public void validateUser(String usermail, String userpassword){
        String url = EndPoint.URL.getUrl() + userpassword;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
               Request.Method.GET, 
               url, 
               response -> userToken = response, 
               error -> setUserRegisterHttpCode(error.networkResponse.statusCode)){
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            setUserRegisterHttpCode(response.statusCode);

            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);

        };
        this.requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: add code please

Comment: No codes, no truth.

Comment: @AswinPAshok , I have added code snippets